# Bash - Shell variable gets promoted to environment variable in child bash process

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

## Question

In Bash, ***shell_variable=value bash child_command*** makes the ***shell_variable*** an environment variable in the ***child_command***.

Is this a build-in shell (sh and bash) feature to promote a shell variable to an environment variable in a child process, and functions like env command?

Trying to find out a documentation explaining this but could not find yet. Appreciate if you could provide a reference.

**hoge.sh**

```
env | grep BUILD_ID
```

### Example 1

```
BUILD_ID=hoge
bash hoge.sh

[result] (none displayed)
```

### Example 2

```
BUILD_ID=hoge bash hoge.sh

[Result]
BUILD_ID=hoge
```

### Example 3

```
env BUILD_ID=hogehoge bash hoge.sh 

[Result]
BUILD_ID=hogehoge
```

### Reference

- [Jenkins Process Killer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller)

Comment: Documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion -- "... Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX: Section [2.9.1 Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)

> ... the variable assignments shall be exported for the execution environment of the command and shall not affect the current execution environment ...

Also in several shell manuals (search for "simple commands")

---

#### Examples

A variable shall not affect the current execution environment:

```
$ var=33; var=11 echo "$var"; echo "$var"
33
33
```

Variable assignments shall be exported to the execution environment:

```
$ var=33; var=11 sh -c 'echo "$var"'; echo "$var"
11
33
```